# Using [Command] to send game objects from client to server

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity3d-mirror

Is it actually possible?

I have no problem sending individual values back to the server in commands but I can't package them up into a game object (with network identity) and then send pass that as a parameter into a command.

Going by the Mirror documentation it should be possible and I've tried following this exmaple:

```
class Item 
{
    public string name;
}

class Weapon : Item
{
    public int hitPoints;
}

class Armor : Item
{
    public int hitPoints;
    public int level;
}

class Player : NetworkBehaviour
{
    [Command]
    void CmdEquip(Item item)
    {
        // IMPORTANT: this does not work. Mirror will pass you an object of type item
        // even if you pass a weapon or an armor.
        if (item is Weapon weapon)
        {
            // The item is a weapon, 
            // maybe you need to equip it in the hand
        }
        else if (item is Armor armor)
        {
            // you might want to equip armor in the body
        }
    }

    [Command]
    void CmdEquipArmor(Armor armor)
    {
        // IMPORTANT: this does not work either, you will receive an armor, but 
        // the armor will not have a valid Item.name, even if you passed an armor with name
    }
}
```

But I'm having no luck, on the server instead of the object I pass the server has its own copy with its own values.

Any idea of where I'm going wrong?

Comment: Have you tried making your classes `[Serializable]`? For the `CmdEquip` if the parameter is `Item` you will usually always only get an `Item`. Implemented a custom multiuser module lately and usually you would look what type is expected, create an instance of that type and fill it with the received data. If mirror does it different I can't tell you though ;)

Comment: I did add the [Serializable] and [SerializeField] after Rusty mentioned it but no dice. I don't think Mirror makes use of those attributes, could be wrong though!

Comment: These attributes (at least `[Serializable]`) are core `c#` not Unity or Mirror specific ;) I only thought that mirrorigjt be using the Unity serializer which would require these .. see e.g. https://mirror-networking.gitbook.io/docs/guides/data-types

Comment: -> `Classes as long as each field has a supported data type
These will allocate garbage and will be instantiated new on the receiver every time they're sent.` so for the first issue they go the same way as I did -> only the received type matters and you will never get a `Weapon` or `Armor` as parameter. I would recommend an overload for this case

Comment: In general it would help you show us how exactly you are calling the methods ;)

Comment: Thanks derHugo. I didn't go into detail as the docs seem very matter of fact about it working. I basically have an Action class that the player sends to the server, and a Response class that comes back from server to client. I perhaps naively thought this would be a common approach from communication and so would be supported out the box. The values inside can be anything, so just a single int, but the fact it's in a class/struct means the value won't be transferred across. I've replaced the code with passing the values individually.

Comment: I can post an example using classes if you like but it is as simple as I describe above.

Answer (score 0):

It tells in the documentation that "This code does not work out of the box.".
From the docs:
CmdEquip will work if you provide a custom serializer for the Item type.
For example:

```
public static class ItemSerializer 
{
    const byte WEAPON = 1;
    const byte ARMOR = 2;

    public static void WriteItem(this NetworkWriter writer, Item item)
    {
        if (item is Weapon weapon)
        {
            writer.WriteByte(WEAPON);
            writer.WriteString(weapon.name);
            writer.WritePackedInt32(weapon.hitPoints);
        }
        else if (item is Armor armor)
        {
            writer.WriteByte(ARMOR);
            writer.WriteString(armor.name);
            writer.WritePackedInt32(armor.hitPoints);
            writer.WritePackedInt32(armor.level);
        }
    }

    public static Item ReadItem(this NetworkReader reader)
    {
        byte type = reader.ReadByte();
        switch(type)
        {
            case WEAPON:
                return new Weapon
                {
                    name = reader.ReadString(),
                    hitPoints = reader.ReadPackedInt32()
                };
            case ARMOR:
                return new Armor
                {
                    name = reader.ReadString(),
                    hitPoints = reader.ReadPackedInt32(),
                    level = reader.ReadPackedInt32()
                };
            default:
                throw new Exception($"Invalid weapon type {type}");
        }
    }
}
```

So seems you need to pass the serialized info between client and server instead of the raw types for this to work. Just in case you did not have this into account.

Comment: Thanks Rusty. I used that example as it was only code I could find showing an object being passed to the server. I'm talking more generally, the docs state that "Any parameters of allowed data type will be automatically passed to the server with the command." Game objects and structs should work but I've not had any luck either and I've tried every which way. I'll have a look at serialization in case it's something I'm missing.

Comment: I understand "any parameter" as serialized info...however I do not have experience with Mirror although I am interested to pick it up as tech option

Comment: Now's as good a time as any! Not to worry, I'm hoping for those in the know it's an easy answer. When I find out I'll post back here.

Comment: Any luck @cerestorm?

Comment: @babinec I think it was because the variables needed to be public. I've not used Mirror in a long time as I switched over to Netcode for GameObjects.